# WcfFacility missing

Tags: castle-windsor, windsor-facilities

I am looking for the WcfFacility which is supposed to be in Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.

Have things changed? Where is it? I have the latest castle (version 3.1).

The question is related to this link:

[castle wcf integration](http://www.darkside.co.za/archive/2012/05/30/castle-windsor-wcf-self-hosted.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're asking where is it in the [package you download](http://www.castleproject.org/download/)? It's there.[image: WCF Facility, right there]

Or do you mean the [nuget package](http://nuget.org/packages/Castle.WcfIntegrationFacility)

Comment: I meant the nuget package. Thanks that helped!

Comment: I am trying to get this to work: https://mail.google.com/mail/?shva=1#inbox/139731f2870df9ef. Will post something here.